# Two Ajax timer cannot tick simultaneously?

Tags: asp.net

I have two ajax time for my aspx web page but while the one is ticking , the other stops running. How can i make it both timer run together like the windows form?

Answer (score 0):

Put one timer inside your update panel and the other outside it.

Works in .Net 4

Comment: if i put the timer outside the timer, the page will refresh every one minute (my interval) which i don't want. But, I tested as u said and the timer inside the update panel is not ticking.

Comment: Hi sorry, your method is working. But, If I put the timer outside, the whole page also refresh when the outside timer ticks. Is there any other way bcos I don't want to refresh the whole page every about one minute? Thanks.